# image border width border:none?

Tags: html, css

EDIT:
more of my HTML & CSS code.

```
 <div id="wrapper">
            <ul class="menu_pro">
              <li class="homepage"><?php echo link_to('Accueil', 'homepage/index', array('id' => 'homepage')); ?></li>
              <li class="owner"><a class="drop-down-link" href="#">Propriétaire<img class="arrow" /></a>
                <ul class="drop-down">
                  <li class="subitem1"><?php echo link_to('Liste Globale', 'owner/list', array('id' => 'owner_global_list')); ?></li>
                  <li class="subitem2"><?php echo link_to('Fiche personnelle', 'owner/sheet', array('id' => 'owner_personnal_sheet')); ?></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="client"><a id="client" class="drop-down-link" href="#">Client<img class="arrow" /></a>
                <ul class="drop-down">
                  <li class="subitem1"><?php echo link_to('Liste Globale', 'client/list', array('id' => 'client_global_list')); ?></li>
                  <li class="subitem2"><?php echo link_to('Fiche personnelle', 'client/sheet', array('id' => 'client_personnal_sheet')); ?></li>

                </ul>
              </li>
              <li>
              </li>
              .
              .
            </ul>
           </div>
```

now the part of my css :

```
a { text-decoration: none; border:none; color:#888; }
a img { border:none; border-width: 0;}
#wrapper { margin-bottom:20px; list-style:none; position:absolute; width:190px; font-size:1.1em; border-right:1px solid black; padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px; margin-right:5px; background-color:rgba(0, 143, 147, 0.6); display:block; }
.menu_pro { list-style:none; width:auto; height:auto; -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13); -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13); box-shadow:0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13); }
.menu_pro > li > a { text-decoration: none; background-color: #616975; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(114, 122, 134)),to(rgb(80, 88, 100))); background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100)); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100)); background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100)); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100)); background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100)); filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#727a86', EndColorStr='#505864'); border-bottom: 1px solid #33373d; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98; -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98; box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98; width:100%; height:3em; line-height:3em; text-indent:1.2em; display:block; position:relative; font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight:600; color:#fff; text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5); }
.menu_pro ul li a { text-decoration:none; background:#a5bef2; width:100%; height:3em; line-height:3em; text-indent:1.5em; display:block; position:relative; font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:0.923em; font-weight:400; color:black; }
.menu_pro ul li:last-child a { border-bottom: 1px solid #33373d; }
.menu_pro > li > ul li:hover a, .menu_pro > li > ul li:hover a span, .menu_pro > li > ul li:hover a:before { color:yellow; }
.menu_pro > li > a:hover,.menu_pro > li > a.active { background-color:#35afe3; background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from #f60070),to #e2007a)); background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f60070, #e2007a); background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f60070, #e2007a); background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #f60070, #e2007a); background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #f60070, #e2007a); background-image:linear-gradient(top, #f60070, #e2007a); filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#45c7eb', EndColorStr='#2698db'); border-bottom:1px solid #103c56; -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef; -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef; box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef; }
.menu_pro > li > a.active { border-bottom: 1px solid #1a638f; }
.menu_pro > li > a span { font-size:0.857em; display:inline-block; position:absolute; right:1em; top:0%; background:#48515c; line-height:1em; height:1em; /* padding:.4em .6em; margin:-.8em 0 0 0;*/ color:#fff; text-indent:0; text-align:center; -webkit-border-radius:.769em; -moz-border-radius:.769em; border-radius:.769em; -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15); -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15); box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15); text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5); font-weight:500; }
.menu_pro > li > a:hover span, .menu_pro > li a.active span { background:#2173a1; }
.menu_pro ul > li > a span { font-size:0.857em; display:inline-block; position:absolute; right:1em; top:50%; / background:#fff; border:1px solid #d0d0d3; line-height:1em; height:1em; padding:.4em .7em; margin:-.9em 0 0 0; color:#878d95; text-indent:0; text-align:center; -webkit-border-radius:.769em; -moz-border-radius:769em; border-radius:769em; text-shadow:0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.01)); }
.subitem1, .subitem2, .subitem3_, .subitem4, .subitem5, .subitem6, .subitem3 { border-bottom: 1px solid #efeff0; list-style:none; }
.subitem1 a:before, .subitem2 a:before, .subitem3 a:before, .subitem4 a:before, .subitem5 a:before, .subitem6  a:before, .subitem3_a:before { content:'▶'; font-size:8px; color:red; position:absolute; width:1em; height:1em; top:0; left:-1.5em; }
.submit, a.submit { background-color:#707173; color:white; padding:5px 6px; border:none; text-decoration:none; }

.drop-down-link { border:none; }
.arrow img { border:none; border-width: 0;}
```

i've try and add some of your suggest in my code, haven't any good result from now.

@bot look, i add your CSS code i think, see on my browser :

[image]

you can check it here.

//////////////

http://jsfiddle.net/BVYFZ/
update : http://jsfiddle.net/BVYFZ/5/

/////////////

Comment: Why declare class as well as id?

Comment: Could you show the css of #owner and .drop-down-link? and its not a good practice to use them both.

Comment: the id is unused, so i've remove it.

Comment: Check in some tool (like FireFox web developer) css classes applied to your element.

Comment: i've use chrome + F12 and the css classes are applied to elements

Comment: It was inappropriate to replace the question by a statement about assumed answer (without even disclosing the answer). The whole issue was caused by the kludgy use of invalid `img` tags, so the proper fix is to use a completely different technique (for whatever the purpose was).

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts like that. If one of the existing answers solves your problem accept it, if not post your own answer and accept that when you can.

Answer (score 2):

You have a link around your image
so: `#owner{border:none;}`
would solve it

Answer (score 2):

You see links border I guess. Not image border. Try to remove link for testing. Border should disappear in that case.

Comment: its the same with or without the link.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<a id="owner" class="drop-down-link" href="#">Click me</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#owner{
background-image: url(next.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position-x: 51px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
width: 100px;
background-size: 18px;
}

a
{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: i add your code but instead of #owner i use .drop-down-link ( I remove the id because is unused ) and its not working.

Comment: Ok, i've fix it, but i don't understand why just including the src on every img fix it, and i cant just set background-image for my all images class.

Comment: yes, you can but there is some z-index is hiding that arrow......if want i will try it for, but i need some time.

Comment: if i set z-index:10; on my class arrow the result is the same

Answer (score 2):

Set border-width of image to Zero

```
img { border-width: 0; }
```

Comment: i've add that to my css, see my first message edit, its not working :/

Comment: Do create a JsFiddle of what you have tried, it will be easy to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. It seems you are applying `background-image` property for `img` tag, that's a bad practice. Either add `src` to your image tag or replace `img` with `div` or `span` and apply `background-image`

Answer (score 2):

The border is not caused by the code posted (which is defective anyway – an `img` element without `src` and without `alt` is pointless and invalid). It is caused by some setting elsewhere, a setting that causes `border-style` to be set to something else than `none`, overriding the CSS rule included in the question.

You can see this by testing your code in isolation, i.e. in a document that contains nothing but that code (and obligatory formalities).

Comment: i cant find any border-style in my css

Answer (score 1):

Use only either of **#owner** and **.drop-down-link** to use in your `<a></a>`
 because you could also apply what is in the css of **.drop-down-link** to **#owner** so why use them both?
for example you choose **#owner** and remove **.drop-down-link** you could have this in your css

```
#owner {some style here you could add the css of .drop-down-link here so to use only one id/class}
#owner img {border:none;}
```

or the best bet for this to remove the border is to identify the wrapper that wrap outside the `<a></a>` example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<a id="owner" href="#">Propriétaire<img source /></a>
</div>
```

so the css is

```
.wrapper {some style here }
.wrapper img{ border:none;}
```

P.S if you want to use both #owner and .drop-down-link it will be fine anyway. :)

Comment: "*Use only either of **#owner** and **.drop-down-link** to use in your <a></a>*"??? Why?

Comment: .arrow img {border:none} won't work because it assumes your img is a child of .arrow in this case img has the class arrow therefor: img.arrow{border:none;}

Comment: i've add your code on my edit message, its not working either.

Comment: @MatthiasWegtun yeah.. thanks.. Sorry I haven't saw that I changed my answer

Comment: @MyHeadHurts because you could also apply the css of #owner to .drop-down-link so why use both? But If you like to use them both it will be fine anyway. :) I just only have a practice that use only one of them. :P

Comment: @bot why .wrapper ? on my update you can see #wrapper img { border: none; } and you want to replace #wrapper by .wrapper ? wrapper its only an ID not a class in my html

Comment: @bot i've edit my question, i've add a jsFiddle, can you check it pls ?

Comment: @1nsan3 sorry for the late reply. My mistake I'll change it. By the way what border do you want to remove, the border outside your tab? the black on the right side?

Comment: @1nsan3 could you check this fiddle if this is what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/BVYFZ/6/

Comment: @bot its good men, just i need to set the src attribut, i don't inderstand why my background-image on my css class do that, see the difference here :http://jsfiddle.net/BVYFZ/7/